# Using an input to search a local webpage in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, search, local

I'm stuck on this problem for now a couple of days and I have no idea what to do. I want to navigate directly to another page from my own website only by writing the page name(without the ".html" or ".php" in the input.

Example: you write "index" in the textbox and once you click on the submit button it sends you to "http://www.website.com/**index**.html". Instead of doing that, it sends me to "http://www.website.com/?2016=index&.=html"

I got it totally wrong because it sends the input names and some symbols around them.

This is my HTML code:

```
    <form id="newsearch" method="get" action="http://www.website.com/">
    <p>Enter your confirmation number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="searchvalue" class="textbox1" name="2016" size="50" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" class="button1" value=">">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenvalue1" name="." value="html">
    </form>
```

Comment: This seems an odd way for a user to navigate, having to guess at what page file names might be.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's to navigate to a "semi-private" page from an automatic code that my system gave them.

Comment: @snit80 on this code I had no JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code simply submits a form, so it is quite correctly adding the entered value as part of the query string `?2016=index&.=html"`.

To navigate to the location, add a submit handler to the form that cancels the default form navigation and instead sets `window.location` to the relevant value, perhaps something like this:

```
document.getElementById("newsearch").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var searchText = document.getElementById("searchvalue").value;
  var extension = document.getElementById("hiddenvalue1").value;

  window.location = this.action + searchText + "." + extension;
  // or if you don't want to use the form's action attribute to specify
  // the domain you could hardcode it in the function:
  // window.location = "http://www.website.com/" + searchText + "." + extension;
});
```

(Update: the above code would need to be in a script element that is *after* the form element, and/or in a `DOMContentLoaded` or `window.onload` handler.)